# how to access function of parent class in c++ and keep the variable in parent class?

Tags: c++, class

```
 //in GUI.h
class MFCGUI : public camerafunction
{   MFCGUI(){  startdevicevent();    }
    
}

// in camerafunction.h contain both class camerafunction and 
// class systemeventhandler

class SystemEventHandlerImpl;
class camerafunction 
    {
          public :
          void startdeviceevent () 
         {
                system = System::GetInstance();
                systemEventHandler = new SystemEventHandlerImpl(system);
                detectcam();

         }
         void detectcam()
         {
                camList = system->GetCameras(); // null ptr here when called 
                                               // from SystemEventHandlerImpl
         }

       SystemEventHandlerImpl *systemEventHandler;
      SystemPtr system;
      CameraList camList;
      CameraPtr pCam;        .....
   } 

class SystemEventHandlerImpl :public camerafunction
{
   void onDeviceArrival()
    {
     detectcam();
    }

}
```

how does class SystemEventHandlerImpl call the function detectcam() in class camerafunction while maintaining the variable in class camerafunction ?

i have tried class SystemEventHandlerImpl : public camerafunction but failed as camerafunction variables changes.

and variables SystemPtr system, CameraList camList; CameraPtr pCam; cannot be set as static . << unresolved external symbol

Comment: What do you mean by "maintaining the variable"?

Comment: hi,  i declared some variables in camerafunction ( FLIR camera library object )  , when my class SystemEventHandlerImpl  call back detectcam(), it hit a null ptr, most likely the variable is different.

Comment: This code does not compile, so SystemeventHandleImpl does not hit any null pointer. Obviously, detectcam need an instance to be called.

Comment: The unresolved external symbol thing happens because the symbols are not defined. In case of static member variables, defining them is as simple as repeating the declaration outside the class scope (in your implementation file, if you have any) like this: `Type Class::VariableName = Initializer`. If it makes more sense to make them static, definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit edit: I take it back, you *do* want to make the method static. If the variables that are used in it are all also static, that is. You can get rid of the unresolved symbols by defining (initializing) the variables outside class scope.

EDIT: Final answer: Looking at your updated code, the inheritance trick did not work because a new object was created. And you accidentally called the method at that object instead of the one you had created.

In order to call the method properly, `SystemEventHandlerImpl` will have to hold a reference/pointer to the `camerafunction` object, and then call the method from that. I recommend assigning the pointer in a constructor and then calling the constructor like `systemEventHandler = new SystemEventHandlerImpl(system, this);`.

(I will leave the rest here in case someone happens to google it up)

I believe what you are looking for is friendship.

`detectcam` is a private member, so only `camerafunction` can access it. There are several ways to get around that.

You can, of course, declare it as public (`public: void detectcam`), but that is probably not what you want, as then everyone and their mother could access the method.

The inheritance trick you tried *would* work, but not even derived classes can access private members. To give access to a derived class, we have the access specifier `protected` (`protected: void detectcam`). Then again, if you do not want a new `camerafunction` object to be a part of each `SystemEventHandlerImpl` object, that is a bad idea. Given the context, that is probably another reason why it did not work for you (an entire new instance of `camerafunction` was created).

Finally, you can write `friend class SystemEventHandlerImpl` into `camerafunction` (hint: that is probably what you want to do in this case). Now `SystemEventHandlerImpl` can access everything that is inside `camerafunction`.

Also a note, the `[access-specifier]: ...` does not affect a single member, it applies to all members until a new access specifier is used.

Is that entirely different answer than you were looking for?

In case you are trying to call the `detectcam` without any `camerafunction`, you need to prefix the function declaration with `static`. Now it is not bound to an object.

Comment: Hi , so i did this at first. 
systemEventHandler = new SystemEventHandlerImpl(system, this); and have a variable pointer in systemevent class  call camerafunction * sysCam;. Then on the constructor
 SystemEventHandlerImpl::SystemEventHandlerImpl(SystemPtr system, camerafunction* cam)
{
 m_system = system; sysCam = cam;
}

but still cannot access the function using cam->detectcam();

let me try making it static again

Comment: This is an access issue though. Try friending the classes or making the method public.

Comment: If you keep it as private, you won't have access to it even when it's static

Comment: hi, making it static works. though i think pointer will works too, thanks !

Comment: just another qn . right now , class camerafunction and systemevent is in the same file.
if i split them, systemevent into another file . i cant seems to access it camerafunction.

Comment: @Dong Not sure what is happening. Are the files two headers, or a header and implementation? What error message does it give?

Comment: at first, both class are in the same header and cpp. i wan to split them into 2 cpp and 2 header .

Comment: @Dong I suspect it is a chicken-or-egg problem. If the message goes something like "using undefined class", that means the inside of the class is not defined yet. In that case, move the function that causes it to implementation (assuming it's defined in a header) and include the apropriate header there. If it is "symbol already exists" linker error, that also means you need to move the definition to implementation. Otherwise, what message are you getting?

Comment: when i put class systemeventhandler : public camerafunction , i cannot compile , base class undefined. I have declared class camerafunction in systemevent header

Comment: @Dong Yep, that's chicken-or-egg. You need to define `camerafunction` before `SystemEventHandler`. That is a little tricky, as you have a `SystemEventHandler*` in `camerafunction`. You can solve this by declaring `class SystemEventHandler;` in the `camerafunction` header, which allows you to declare a pointer to it (but pretty much nothing else. Make sure *everything* that uses that pointer is in implementation). Then just include the headers in the right order.

Comment: yes. in my camerafunction.h, I include systemevent.h and declared class systemhandler. For systemevent.h, i include camerafunction.h and declare class systemevent : public camerafunction.... base class undefined

Comment: @Dong ...Maybe just declare it as `class SystemEventHandler;`, without the base. You add the base when defining. Also, don't have the headers include each other. Only include `camerafunction.h` in `SystemEventHandler.h`. You can then include them both in each implementation if necessary.

Comment: if i dont use class SystemEventHandler; : public camerafunction , how do i access detectcam() ? if i only include camerafunction.h in SystemEventHandler.h, my camerafunction cannot declare new SystemEventHandler();

Comment: @Dong You don't need to. `SystemEventHandler` is not defined yet, so it does not need access to anything. You inherit it only at definition (eg. declaration: `class SysEvtHandler;`; definition: `class SysEvtHandler : public camfunction {...};`. That being said, if `detectcam` is static, there is no point in inheriting `camerafunction`. A much more natural way would be friending them.

Comment: "if i only include camerafunction.h in SystemEventHandler.h, my camerafunction cannot declare new SystemEventHandler();" It can, if you move that piece of code into implementation. By the time implementation is compiled, both classes have been defined.

Comment: @Dong (forgot to tag you there, did you see my last idea?) With all this, how is it possible that it even worked when they were in the same file? Did you not even get a warning?

Comment: hi , it did work apparently. i updated the code above and that works. now im trying to let it work in diff cpp and header

Comment: i managed to get it running in diff cpp , thnks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `protected` ?

Note: this is a supposition, as the question is not completely clear to me. If you want to access parent class properties, they need to be declared in a `protected` or `public` section.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <iostream>

class camerafunction 
{
protected:
    int systemEventHandler=0;
public:
    void detectcam()
    {
        std::cout << "detectcam"<< std::endl;
    };
};


class MFCGUI : public camerafunction 
{
public:
    void startdeviceevent()
    {
        systemEventHandler = 42;
         std::cout << "startdeviceevent with systemEventHandler=" << systemEventHandler << std::endl;
    }
  
};

class SystemEventHandlerImpl
{
public:
    void onDeviceArrival()
    {
        MFCGUI obj;
        obj.startdeviceevent();
        obj.detectcam();
    }

};


int main()
{
    SystemEventHandlerImpl obj;
    obj.onDeviceArrival();

    return 0;
}
```

Run it online:
https://onlinegdb.com/r1NyfgelO